# The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection. What's the issue with my code?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dataset

This is my code. Can you give some suggestions?

```
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ds = (DSCQM)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, ProcCQM0160B, ds, tableNames, 300);
    });
    thread1.Start();

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ds = (DSCQM)dbManager.ExecuteDataSet(CommandType.StoredProcedure, ProcCQM0160C, ds, tableNames, 300);
    });
    thread2.Start();
```

Comment: You're doing two threads for the same DataSet? Whatever ExecuteDataSet is doing, it is not threadsafe. Most of the types aren't.

Comment: You mean, other then the fact it makes no sense to fill a database by executing the same stored procedure in two different threads? The error message is pretty self explanatory - you can't use the same SQLParameter instance in more than one instance of SqlCommand.

Comment: @ZoharPeled they are calling `ProcCQM0160B` and `ProcCQM0160C` so those are different SP's I assume but that doesn't matter for the root cause which is as you analyzed

Comment: @rene good catch! didn't see that difference.